# Trying to select and upload a picture to a server in android

Tags: android, crash, logcat

I am trying to select and image that is stored locally and then send it to a server running within eclipse. I select the photo menu item and then the program crashes. I am successfully using the same server to access a data file to send and return data on individual items but can't get the image to work

below is the photo code:

```
public class EnteringPhotoActivity extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener {


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_send_photo);

        storePhoto("bolts.jpg", R.drawable.bolts);
        storePhoto("hammer.jpg", R.drawable.hammer);
        storePhoto("screws.jpg", R.drawable.screws);

        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.url_spinner);
        // Create an ArrayAdapter using a string array and a default spinner
        // layout
        String[] files = this.fileList();

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) 
        {
            System.out.println(files[i]);
        }

        @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, files);

        // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        // Apply the adapter to the spinner
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

private void storePhoto(String p, int id) 
{
    try 
    {
        InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(id);

        FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(p, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        byte buf[] = new byte[1024];
        int len;

        while ((len = inputStream.read(buf)) > 0)
        {
            fos.write(buf, 0, len);
            fos.close();
            inputStream.close();
        }

    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
    {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.itemmenu, menu);
        return true;
    }


    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) 
    {
        String file = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(pos);
        new ImageLoadingTask().execute(file);
    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void displayImage(Drawable image) 
    {
        ImageView iv = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.iv_image);

        iv.setImageDrawable(image);

    }

    public class ImageLoadingTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Drawable> 
    {

        @Override
        protected Drawable doInBackground(String... params) {
            Socket socket = null;
            PrintWriter out = null;
            OutputStream os = null;
            Drawable d = null;

            try {
                // open the local file
                FileInputStream is = openFileInput(params[0]);

                // create a Drawable object
                d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src");
                is.close();

                // open a network socket 

                if (socket == null) 
                {
                    InetAddress ia = InetAddress.getByName("10.0.2.2");
                    socket = new Socket(ia, 4444);
                    System.err.println("Created Socket");
                    out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
                    System.err.println("Output stream created");
                }
                out.println("SEND_PHOTO");
                // send the file name
                out.println(params[0]);
                // open a binary output stream
                os = socket.getOutputStream();
                // read the image from file and send it to the server
                is = openFileInput(params[0]);

                byte buf[] = new byte[1024];
                int len;

                while ((len = is.read(buf)) > 0) 
                {
                    os.write(buf, 0, len);
                    os.flush();
                }
                os.close();

            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 

            catch (UnknownHostException e) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
            catch (IOException e) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            // return the Drawable object to be displayed
            return d;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Drawable result) 
        {
            // update the UI with loaded information
            displayImage(result);
        }

    }

}
```

below is the logcat:

```
12-04 23:19:44.107: E/AndroidRuntime(1898): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-04 23:19:44.107: E/AndroidRuntime(1898): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.assignmentfinal/com.example.assignmentfinal.EnteringPhotoActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: asset
12-04 23:19:44.107: E/AndroidRuntime(1898):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
12-04 23:19:44.107: E/AndroidRuntime(1898):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
12-04 23:19:44.107: E/AndroidRuntime(1898):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
12-04 23:19:44.107: E/AndroidRuntime(1898):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
12-04 23:19:44.107: E/AndroidRuntime(1898):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-04 23:19:44.107: E/AndroidRuntime(1898):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-04 23:19:44.107: E/AndroidRuntime(1898):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
12-04 23:19:44.107: E/AndroidRuntime(1898):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-04 23:19:44.107: E/AndroidRuntime(1898):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-04 23:19:44.107: E/AndroidRuntime(1898):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
12-04 23:19:44.107: E/AndroidRuntime(1898):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
12-04 23:19:44.107: E/AndroidRuntime(1898):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-04 23:19:44.107: E/AndroidRuntime(1898): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: asset
12-04 23:19:44.107: E/AndroidRuntime(1898):     at android.content.res.AssetManager.readAsset(Native Method)
12-04 23:19:44.107: E/AndroidRuntime(1898):     at android.content.res.AssetManager.access$700(AssetManager.java:35)
12-04 23:19:44.107: E/AndroidRuntime(1898):     at android.content.res.AssetManager$AssetInputStream.read(AssetManager.java:573)
12-04 23:19:44.107: E/AndroidRuntime(1898):     at com.example.assignmentfinal.EnteringPhotoActivity.storePhoto(EnteringPhotoActivity.java:72)
12-04 23:19:44.107: E/AndroidRuntime(1898):     at com.example.assignmentfinal.EnteringPhotoActivity.onCreate(EnteringPhotoActivity.java:36)
12-04 23:19:44.107: E/AndroidRuntime(1898):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
12-04 23:19:44.107: E/AndroidRuntime(1898):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
12-04 23:19:44.107: E/AndroidRuntime(1898):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
12-04 23:19:44.107: E/AndroidRuntime(1898):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: asset
12-04 23:19:44.107: E/AndroidRuntime(1898):     at android.content.res.AssetManager.readAsset(Native Method)
12-04 23:19:44.107: E/AndroidRuntime(1898):     at android.content.res.AssetManager.access$700(AssetManager.java:35)
12-04 23:19:44.107: E/AndroidRuntime(1898):     at android.content.res.AssetManager$AssetInputStream.read(AssetManager.java:573)
12-04 23:19:44.107: E/AndroidRuntime(1898):     at com.example.assignmentfinal.EnteringPhotoActivity.storePhoto(EnteringPhotoActivity.java:72)` - what's line 72?

Comment: BTW, learn to use the debugger.  You would find this in seconds.  `System.err.println("Output stream created");` is a lousy way to debug.

Comment: `while ((len = inputStream.read(buf)) > 0)` and this is in the method `private void storePhoto(String p, int id) 
 {
  try 
  {
   InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(id);
   
   FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(p, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
   
   byte buf[] = new byte[1024];
   int len;
   
   while ((len = inputStream.read(buf)) > 0)
   {
    fos.write(buf, 0, len);
    fos.close();
    inputStream.close();
   }
   
  } 
  catch (IOException e) 
  {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }`

Comment: and sorry im fairly new to this

Comment: Which line, just the line, is line 72?

Comment: `while ((len = inputStream.read(buf)) > 0)`

Comment: `buf` can't be null, since you just created it so `inputStream` must be null.  In turn, this suggests that the resource referenced by `id` does not exist.  Where and how do you call `storePhoto`?  Only in `onCreate()`?

Comment: Ah, just spotted it.  please read the documentation for `openRawResource()`

Comment: yeah i call it with the images

Comment: `storePhoto("bolts.jpg", R.drawable.bolts);
storePhoto("hammer.jpg", R.drawable.hammer);  storePhoto("screws.jpg", R.drawable.screws);`

Comment: Well, I'm stuck.  Best advice is to invest 30 minutes now learning the basics of the debugger.  It will pay back many many times in the future.  Put a breakpoint on that line and work backwards.  Very simple to solve with the debugger.

Comment: I have just done that and it is saying that the value mMarkPos within the InputStream is 0 which i guess is the issue but no idea what this means